# excel vba reading dd/mm/yyyy as mm/dd/yyyy - pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I'm reading through a list of dates in a pivot table using **PivotItems Value** variable e.g.

```
For Each Pi In pf.PivotItems
  If IsDate(Pi.Value) Then
      If format(Pi.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") >= Invoice_Start_Date And format(Pi.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") <= Invoice_End_Date Then
            Pi.Visible = True
      Else
            Pi.Visible = False
      End If
  Else
    Pi.Visible = False
  End If
Next
```

I'm trying to check that the value is between 2 dates but for some reason excel/vba is reading the contents of the pivot field as **mm/dd/yyyy** instead of **dd/mm/yyyy**.  The format of the cells are set to **dd/mm/yyyy**.

I dont understand why it's switching it round?

thanks
Craig.

Comment: Try to read the dates as numbers instead of dates in the code. You can convert any date to number just using `CDbl(datevalue)`. And then make the comparison

Comment: It switches around cause VBA uses the American format. What does `Datevalue(Pi.Value)` do for you?

Comment: I tried DateValue but it does the same.. switches it around.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I tried to use  **CDbl(PivotField.Value)** but am receiving a **Type Mistmatch** error on this value?

Comment: Check @SerhiiPoklonskyi answer. Try `CDbl(Cdate(PivotField.Value))`. If this gives error, means Excel is not recognizing your dates in any way and you need a different approach

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  I tried the above and it eventually was able to compare start and end dates.. however, I'm getting Odd results being displayed in the Pivot table.  Some dates are not showing in the results even though stepping through the code it returns a positive value (ie  Visible.True) but it doesnt show.  I also have to click on the Filter button and select "All" to reset the Pivot table

Comment: All those new problems should go to another question, with data example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, unable to comment. Try CDbl(CDate(dateValue))
Given that Excel understands that input is a date and able to convert it with CDate, it can then cast CDbl. Otherwise you are trying to convert string

In addition: do check what the type of Pi.Value is. It looks like Excel doesn't think you have dates there. Otherwise you wouldn't get 'Type mismatch'

Answer (score 0):

The date-time format is usually dependent on what the local language/region is. 
I would check your language, and change it.